# File Upload with GeoEXT FormPanel

Tags: javascript, geoext

I have a GeoExt form and want to do file upload here. But it never works with GeoEXT. I have this:

```
buttons: [{
text: 'Загрузить',
handler: function(){
if(fp.getForm().isValid() && Ext.getCmp('opinions').getValue()=="blabla"){
form_action=1;
fp.getForm().submit({
         url: '<portlet: actionURL>',
         waitMsg: 'WAITING...',
 success: function(fp, o) {
          DO SOMETHING
          }
         }
        }
      }]
```

This is correct?

What arguments use in success: function(fp, o)? First argument is FormPanel but I don't understand what is second. Another question how to do asynchronous file upload in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think "o" is result of your process. if not, you can easily learn what it is with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)...

```
  ...  
  success: function(fp, o) {
      consolo.log(o)
                 };
```

and you can check out exm. about file upload with geoext [here](http://trac.geoext.org/browser/ext/3.0.0/examples/form/file-upload.js?rev=1266).

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Yes, thank you. File upload with this library really simple.

Comment: And another question what is `form_action=1;`? cant find this in GeoEXT documentations. Looks like simple variable. Its impotant thing to form submit?